# Java project with a database(.sqlite) not working in .jar file when trying to add data

Tags: java, sqlite

I am working on a project.The project is working well when I am running it in java `Netbeans IDE`.

Now, I have made a `.jar file` of the project(`using clean and build`). The `dist` folder has been successfully made and I have a copy of my database in this folder.

Now when I am opening my application using this jar file, the values ,which I have to save into my database(through a button called `ADD EMPLOYEE`), are not being saved in the database.

What is the problem and any solution will be very much helpful?

Comment: are you getting any exception while running jar file?
try to run your jar file using command prompt using java -jar jarfile.jar to see the errors.

Comment: You haven't provided us with enough information to help you. You really need to offer a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It would be better to understand your query if you post your code here

Answer (score 0):

put your jar file and the SQLite file in the same folder and then run it worked for me